# What is the best component structure for dynamic tabs in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a Figma clone. I have what I think is a simple problem. In Figma, you can add lines, images, rectangles, **+ 20** other types of design elements.

The issue I have is that when you **click** on these design elements, an **inspector** shows up, which is **different for each element** (the rectangle inspector is different from the image inspector).

So, would I have to make 2**0 different components** for each design element? What is the best way to structure this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do that making all input and button you need in a different component, so can import them like this :

```
import {SizeInput, ColorInput, SomthingInput} from InspectInputs;
```

Then make an object for each element u have, like this :

```
const inspect = {
  rectangle : [
     <SizeInput />,
     <ColorInput />,
  ],
  image : [
     <SizeInput />,
     <ColorInput />,
     <SomthingInput />
  ],
};
```

And finally use them like this :

```
const Inspector = ({type}) => (
      <div>{inspect[type].map((child) => child)}</div>;
)
```

**Example**

```js
const inputChange = (e) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
};
const inspectArray = [
  {
    name: "Rectangle",
    element: [
      <input type="text" key="1" />,
      <input type="range" key="2" />,
      <input type="color" key="3" onInput={inputChange} />,
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Image",
    element: [
      <div key="1">
        <input type="text" key="1.1" value="Some Value" />
        <input type="text" key="1.2" />
      </div>,
      <input type="range" key="2" />,
      <input type="color" key="3" onInput={inputChange} />,
    ],
  },
];
const Inspector = ({ index }) =>
  index !== null && (
    <div
      style={{
        width: 300,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
      }}
    >
      <h1>{inspectArray[index].name}</h1>
      {inspectArray[index].element.map((child) => child)}
    </div>
  );
function App() {
  const [inspect, setInspect] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <div>
      {inspectArray.map((item, i) => (
        <button key={i} onClick={() => setInspect(i)}>
          {item.name}
        </button>
      ))}
      <Inspector index={inspect} />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

You can Make your array element like a component and use `onChange` or `onInput` function for everything or make them separate, super simple.

Comment: Oh awesome!! This looks great. How could I pass props into the `SizeInput` or `ColorInput`?

Comment: use Context or Redux for managing props and states. for something big as Figma should probably use state managment library

Comment: of course for somthing not comlicated like key u can pass on every child like this `<SizeInput key="1" />`

Comment: Yeah, but I guess Im a bit confused about how you would even provide the key? Any chance you could provide an example in your answer?

Comment: @NickSmith check example.

Comment: @NickSmith no problem, happy to help you :)